# deferredLocationUpdate iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, location

I have looked up about 3 different pages on how this works. But, I could really use some help because I am getting kCLError = 15. Here is what I have so far then I will explain more.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self]
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%@",[locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%d",[CLLocationManager deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable]);
    [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocationDistanceMax timeout:CLTimeIntervalMax];
```

After this I have my error code

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *stringError = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: %@",[error description]];
    _whatMonitor.text = stringError;
}
```

So, anyone that can help me I will seriously be so thankful. I have a count of the locations array as well, but this never changes from 1.. It is my understanding that after closing app to home screen and locking the device, the deferredUpdates should kick in. I have checked the [locations count] and it is still 1. I am expecting it to be greater than this..

I do not claim to be very good at this, so if I am making a careless mistake please let me know. I did not copy and paste so there may be some small typos. Thanks in advance.

I am running iOS 6.0 on an iPhone 5.

Comment: Did you enable the location UIBackgroundMode? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Yes, I have that enabled

Comment: Other than my battery has not run down quickly, I have do not have any reason to believe it is working.. But I have not moved in awhile either.. Not since I last went outside to do some testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For significant change service and deferred location updates you have to move for the system to record an update.  You have specified CLLocationDistanceMax which is a high value for distance.  You can specify a lower distance to get more frequent changes for example you could specify every 100 meter change to trigger an update as follows:

```
[locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocation(100) timeout:CLTimeIntervalMax];
```

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: I added code to post coordinates to a mySQL database when updating and it worked as expected. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Now it seems to stop after awhile.. I want to say it lasts longer than 10 minutes but I cannot be sure. Is it supposed to stop updating location after a certain period of time?

Comment: Ok I changed a viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear and it fixed the issue.